# YUI3 Dependency management

Tags: javascript, yui, dependency-management, yui3

I am trying to develop a web application leveraging the YUI 3 app framework and am not able to  figure out how the dependancy management actually works.

I wish to define a module that I want to reuse for another location in a different file.Here is the code I use to define the module in some file **dir1/home/home.js**:

`YUI.add('MyModule_Home',function(Y){
    Y.namespace("mysite.home");
    Y.mysite.home.SomeView = Y.base.create("SomeView", Y.View, {
        initializer : function() {
            // some logic goes here ... 
        }
        // more functions go here ....
    }
},'0.1',{ requires : ['base','node','app'] });  // <---- Dependency Specifications`

In another File (index.js) to use this module I use :

`YUI( {
  groups: {
    grp1: {
      base: "/path/to/dir1/",
      modules: {
        MyModule_Home: {
          path: "home/home.js",
          requires: ['base', 'node', 'app'] // <------ Dependency Specifications
        }
      }
    }
  }
})`

The above code works, but I would like to know why are the redundant dependency specifications required at both places. If I omit the dependency specification while loading the module or while defining the module I get errors. Is there a more succinct way of doing this ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I recall using `_` in a module name is not fully supported by YUI3, maybe it's just this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without specifying the dependencies up front in the config object you pass to `YUI()` it has no way of knowing what modules it needs to get before it can load your `MyModule_Home` module. If you don't specify the metadata in the config object it *should* go load your module, read the requirements, and then go load them. This is sub-optimal performance-wise but can be a workable solution while developing.

Just make sure to go back & fix it later!

The YUI team uses the [builder](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/builder/wiki/WikiStart) to wrap their modules in `YUI.add` calls & that handles the metadata for those modules. I find that to be an unnecessary heavy workflow so I maintain the metadata in two places. It ends up not being that large a maintenance cost in my experience.